# Trouble Installing Backpack 6.x in Laravel 10.10: Seeking Resolution

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

[attacch the composer json image also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsB8q.png)[i attached the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXyca.png)I'm facing difficulties while attempting to install the Backpack package in my Laravel project. At present, my Laravel version is "laravel/framework": "^10.10".

The objective is to integrate Backpack version 6.x into my Laravel application. However, throughout the installation process, I'm encountering multiple errors hindering successful integration.

Here are the steps I've taken and the errors encountered:

I initiated the installation process using the command composer require backpack/base.
The error message I encountered stated [    - backpack/crud[0.4.1, ..., 0.9.10, 2.0.0, ..., 2.0.24, 3.0.0, ..., 3.0.9] require illuminate/support ~5.1 -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
].
I also attempted to [mention any alternative approaches or adjustments made].
I'm seeking guidance or a solution to overcome these errors and successfully integrate the Backpack package (version 6.x) into my Laravel application, considering the compatibility issues or any necessary adjustments needed.

Thank you for any assistance or insights provided.

Comment: Please provide the error messages and alternative approaches.

Comment: i attached the screenshot of the error ,iam facing check it

Comment: Show us your composer.json, please. You appear to have quite a few packages locked to old versions.

Comment: check it now i will update the composer json screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `composer require backpack/crud`.
`backpack\base` was last used in v3 ? I think ?
It's a very very old package, it shouldn't even be possible to install on Laravel 10.

Please follow the official installation docs: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/installation#install-using-composer

Comment: I will follow the instructions in the official Backpack documentation installation video, yet I'm encountering the same error again.